# Python and __str__() method - bad practice or not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I've run into certain code snippet which recreates some objects every time in the `__str__` method of a class.

From what I recall, the `__str__` method shouldn't bother with object creation. It should just do simple formatting operations and return a string.

But I do not have any evidence for such statement. Is there any convention or perhaps a PEP explaining proper `__str__` usage? I've found only PEPs regarding `str` vs. `repr` usage.

I've searched Stack Overflow, but I haven't found an answer.

**Edit:**

You've asked for example. Unfortunately I can't share the snippet, because it isn't mine. 
I'm asking for **general guidelines** by the community (if such thing exists).

Here's a **roughly similar** usage:

```
from collections import OrderedDict


class A:

    def __init__(self, a, b, c):

        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def __str__(self):
        # recreated every time...
        dict_sorted = OrderedDict(sorted(self.__dict__.items()))
        result = []
        for i in dict_sorted.keys():
            result.append(str((i, dict_sorted[i])))
        return ' '.join(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = A('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
    print(a)
```

Comment: In general, why create new objects when you don't have to? If all you want to do is print something, then keep it simple.

Comment: Could you provide references to the code snippet you're talking about, and the PEPs you refer to? The [docs on Python's data model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) only specify what you should return - without seeing the specific example it's hard to offer advice, but generally `__str__` shouldn't be doing much work.

Comment: Creates objects in order to assemble the string representation, or creates objects for some other purpose? Usually you at least have to create one or more string objects to create the string representation, and that's perfectly okay. Could you show a concrete example?

Comment: @Cyber I agree. But I'm curious if there is a standard, a document created for the community which shows "the right way".

Comment: @jonrsharpe the code snippet isn't mine and unfortunately I can't share it. I'm asking for a general guideline. The PEPs I refer to are irrelevant - e.g. [3140](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3140/)

Comment: @patriciasz could you at least make a representative example? It's hard to provide a good answer to such a general case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is totally okay, to create objects in the `__str__` method. Python is a object oriented language, that creates objects all the time. In your example, a `OrderedDict`, a list, a key-iterator, some tuples and strings are created.
Would you also have doubts with this `__str__`-method?

```
 def __str__(self):
     return ' '.join(str(item) for item in sorted(self.__dict__.items()))
```

It does exactly the same as your `__str__`-method, but creates a few methods less.
There are no restrictions to a `__str__`-method, other than to return a string object. But the general advice for programmers holds true: a method shouldn't do something unexpected: so `__str__` should create a string representation and nothing else.